# Unable to use init block to initialize property

Tags: kotlin

I am getting errors when I try to use init block to initialize properties in below code. I know I can initialize this property immediately but suppose I would like to compute this value somehow.

```
class SomeClass {
    init {
        someVar = 123  // Variable cannot be initialized before declaration 
    }
    var someVar : Int
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }

}

class SomeClass2 {
    var someVar : Int  // Property must be initialized  
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }
    init {
        someVar = 123
    }
}

class SomeClass3 {
    var someVar : Int = 123 // No errors here
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }
}
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't work only with custom getter/setter. If `set` instead of `set(value) { field = value }` suffices (e.g. if you want to declare it `private set`), then it compiles. Otherwise, if it's something complicated, I think you should initialize it with method call.

Comment: Thanks, I found also that changing `init {` to `constructor() {` fixes all the errors. What is the difference between `init` and `constructor` here?

Comment: This docs https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors may be helpful. Essentially, init blocks are called for every constructor, and you can interleave it with property declarations (for constructors you have to declare all properties outside the constructor).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65868521/initialize-variable-in-init-block-and-define-a-setter-for-the-variable-in-kotlin